# create folder with new name if it already exists

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a folder with specific name in a directory and if it already exists, it should create a folder with the same name but adding an index at the end. For instance creating folder `2017-07-31` in `D:\path` and if it exists, creates `2017-07-31_1` and if it still exists, creates `2017-07-31_2` etc.

```
set foldername=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%
set path=D:\path
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better get the date in a locale/user settings independent format with wmic.

```
@Echo off

For /f "delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) Do Set DT=%%A
Set "foldername=%DT:~0,4%-%DT:~4,2%-%DT:~6,2%"

If Not Exist "%foldername%" MD "%foldername%" >Nul &goto :Next
Set Num=1
:loop
If Exist "%foldername%_%Num%" Set /A Num+=1 & goto :loop
MD "%foldername%_%Num%" >Nul

:Next
:: your further code goes here
```

Comment: will take a look tomorrow and accept the answer. thanks :-)